# Poetry Install crashes because excluded dependency cannot be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab, gitlab-ci, python-poetry

One of our repositories relies on another first-party one. Because we're in the middle of a migration from (a privately hosted) gitlab to azure, some of our dependencies aren't available in gitlab, which is where the problem comes up.

Our pyproject.toml file has this [poetry group](https://python-poetry.org/docs/1.2/managing-dependencies/):

```
# pyproject.toml

[tool.poetry.group.cli.dependencies]
cli-parser = { path = "../cli-parser" }
```

In the Gitlab-CI, this cannot resolve. Therefore, we want to run the pipelines without this dependency. There is no code being run that actually relies on this library, nor files being imported. Therefore, we factored it out into a separate [poetry group](https://python-poetry.org/docs/1.2/managing-dependencies/). In the gitlab-ci, that looks like this:

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml
install-poetry-requirements:
  stage: install
  script:
    - /opt/poetry/bin/poetry --version
    - /opt/poetry/bin/poetry install --without cli --sync
```

As visible, poetry is instructed to omit the cli dependency group. However, it still crashes on it:

```
# Gitlab CI logs
$ /opt/poetry/bin/poetry --version
Poetry (version 1.2.2)
$ /opt/poetry/bin/poetry install --without cli --sync
Directory ../cli-parser does not exist
```

If I comment out the cli-parser line in pyproject.toml, it will install successfully (and the pipeline passes), but we cannot do that because we need it in production.

I can't find another way to tell poetry to omit this library. Is there something I missed, or is there a workaround?

Comment: This will probably work from Poetry 1.4 on. See https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry-core/pull/520

Comment: That looks promising for the future, and I failed to find that by myself earlier.

Answer (score 2):

## Good, Permanent Solution

As [finswimmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9750706/finswimmer) mentioned in a comment, [Poetry 1.4](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry-core/pull/520) should handle this perfectly good. If you're reading this question after it is published, the code in the question should resolve any issues.

## Hacky, Bad, Temporary Solution

Since the original problem was in gitlab CI pipelines, I used a workaround there. Right in front of the install command, I used the following command:

```bash
sed -i '/cli-parser/d' pyproject.toml
```

This modifies the projects' `pyproject.toml` in-place to remove the line that has my module. This prevents poetry from ever parsing the dependency.

See the [sed man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) for more information on how this works.

Keep in mind that if your pipeline has any permanent effects, like for example turning your package into an installable wheel, or build artifacts being used elsewhere, this WILL break your setup.